# Write a new text without losing the previous value.in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qfile, qiodevice

How can i Write a new text without losing the previous value

```
    QString mFilename2 = "bin/bin_2.txt";
File_main_Editor.stWrite(mFilename2,okline_Edit);
```

---

```
void stWrite(QString Filename,QString stringtext){
QFile mFile(Filename);

if(!mFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text))
{
    QMessageBox message_file_Write;
    message_file_Write.warning(0,"Open Error"
           ,"could not to open file for Writing");
    return;
}
QTextStream out(&mFile);
out << stringtext;
out.setCodec("UTF-8");

mFile.flush();
mFile.close();
}
```

Every time that okline_Edit is initialized
stWrite function called a new value in the file is poured .txt previous value is lost.

Or in other words

[image]

Comment: try this `mFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text | QIODevice::Append)`   [ref. for OpenModeFlag](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#OpenModeFlag-enum)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `QIODevice::Append` when you `open()` the file.

```
mFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Append | QIODevice::Text)
```

Additionally, if you want each append to be on a new line, you will have to insert a `\n` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You open file with `QIODevice::WriteOnly` that would start writing...well from start, you need to open it with `QIODevice::Append`